# Should I edit an accepted answer to link to my library?

Tags: discussion

Original question: [How do I create an in-memory handle in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569/how-do-i-create-an-in-memory-handle-in-haskell)

This was asked two years ago; at the time, the answer was "not possible due to library limitations". However, since then the limitations have been fixed, and I wrote a library which solves the original problem.

I added an answer with a link, but since it's down at the bottom it will probably never be seen.

Is it OK to edit the accepted answer to point to my library?

Comment: There seems to be a few people who watch the "active" tab of `haskell`, so your answer will likely get enough votes to rise to the spot just below the accepted one. The owner of the question also appears to still be active on SO, so there's still a chance he will change the accepted answer to yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you shouldn't ever do this. I know that answer *might* be wrong but it shouldn't be edited from

```
You can't
```

to

```
You can
```

Just give OP some time to reaccept other answer (he was last seen 2 days ago).

Answer (score -1):

Normally, I'd say "yes". And I'd still say *someone* should edit the answer, if it is indeed now incorrect and the asker doesn't respond by changing the accepted answer.

But you should probably avoid editing in a link to your own project, simply to avoid the appearance of impropriety. Leave a comment if you're concerned someone might miss your answer.

Comment: -1: I don't think you should edit the accepted answer to change the meaning.  However, I'd agree that editing someone else's post to include a link to your library should be avoided, so +1 for that.  Net result is no vote.

Comment: Interesting... You can't see changing the accepted answer [even if it is blatantly wrong and could potentially cause serious grief to future readers?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-should-we-handle-obsolete-answers) I'd love to hear your reasoning...

Comment: No, I can't.  Adding a new answer will bump the question, and allow the community to vote and choose the best answer.  The accepted answer  is the one explicitly chosen by the OP which solved the problem when it was originally written.  It will only continue to mean that if we disallow major edits.  I *can* see adding a "**Notice:  This answer is out-of-date**" message, but reversal of the meaning of the post is uncalled for.  What if the new answer is wrong?

Comment: If the new answer is wrong, then editing it into an existing answer is a poor idea. So is posting it as an answer. I get where you're coming from, but I'm not talking about subtle or controversial subjects where the "correct" answer might depend on the specific circumstances of the person reading it; rather, if an answer that was once correct but is now obsolete has been accepted, editing is the only way for the *community* to directly correct things (the asker unaccepting it and a moderator deleting it are the other options). Remember, editing bumps too...